# Mapbox GL JS ImageSource wrong coordinates

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, coordinate-systems, mercator

I'm struggling to position an image correctly onto my map. I'm using one of the following URLs for my (live) image:

- https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=dwd:RX-Produkt&styles=&width=1024&height=1024&srs=EPSG:3857&bbox=230596.40272276622,5934337.07299266,1750026.7710981474,7343518.710858418&format=image/png&transparent=true
- https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=dwd:RX-Produkt&styles=&width=1024&height=1024&srs=CRS:84&bbox=2.0714827302884133,47.14423415016973,15.72075796095801,55.07980923136505&format=image/png&transparent=true
- https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=dwd:RX-Produkt&styles=&srs=EPSG:1000001&bbox=-523.462,-4658.645,376.538,-3758.645&width=1024&height=1024&format=image/png&transparent=true

These are the associated WMS capabilities: https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

I tried adding an image source according to this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/). Using these coordinates:

```
[2.0714827302884133, 55.07980923136505],
[15.72075796095801, 55.07980923136505],
[15.72075796095801, 47.14423415016973],
[2.0714827302884133, 47.14423415016973]
```

The problem is that the image is not aligned 100 % correctly, but slightly shifted/stretched. I read something about Mapbox using the Mercator projection and not being able to handle others? That's why there are three different URLs above, but all of them fail. Next I tried to convert my coordinates like this:

```
var westLongitude = 2.0714827302884133;
var eastLongitude = 15.72075796095801;  
var southLatitude = 47.14423415016973;
var northLatitude = 55.07980923136505;  

var topLeft = { lng: westLongitude, lat: northLatitude};
var mTopLeft = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(topLeft, 0).toLngLat();

var topRight = { lng: eastLongitude, lat: northLatitude};
var mTopRight = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(topRight, 0).toLngLat();

var bottomRight = { lng: eastLongitude, lat: southLatitude};
var mBottomRight = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(bottomRight, 0).toLngLat();

var bottomLeft = { lng: westLongitude, lat: southLatitude};
var mBottomLeft = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(bottomLeft, 0).toLngLat();

var mercatorCoordinates = [[mTopLeft.lng, mTopLeft.lat], [mTopRight.lng, mTopRight.lat], [mBottomRight.lng, mBottomRight.lat], [mBottomLeft.lng, mBottomLeft.lat]];
```

However this also didn't align the image correctly. I think, I'm using wrong coordinates. Any idea how to do it right?

Thank you so much.

Here's code to play around with (**please compare the location of the radar blind spot (grey) with the image below to see the offset**): [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/av1kpnej/2/)

Here's where the radar blind spot (pink) has to be:
[image]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codebin showing the issue with images stretching/shifting?

Comment: Like this @SteveBennett? I added a js fiddle and an image. Thanks

Comment: By the way, using Mapbox's macOS API I have the same misalignment.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I don't see anything obviously wrong, when using the CRS:84 version. An issue with projections, but I don't know what. Surprised the server wouldn't accept EPSG:4326. Asking on gis.stackexchange.com might give better results, as your code seems to be ok.

Comment: Thanks! I will ask there, too.

Comment: Tried different coordinates/projections and it works.

Comment: Hello, I work with American radar data. I was wondering - where do you get the European reflectivity data from? I would love some insight on this if possible.

Comment: Hi, I think you are talking about the radar data I use? It's covering mainly Germany and is available for free (due to a new law): https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/geowebservice/geowebservice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following coordinates/projection seems to work:

```
CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=614360.8293587392,5933210.01991552,1713821.866597408,7423590.537061271
```

Here's another [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jnh1yda/1/).